# Youtube video html code that runs any Youtube video URL on a web page

Tags: javascript, html, video, youtube

I am trying to code that runs any Youtube video URL. For example these are the urls

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XGSy3_Czz8k
```

`Iframe` doesn't run the URL that contains `watch` text. What html or JS code should be used to run any video format on web page?

Comment: You can't run youtube video with watch in its URL

Comment: If you want that then you have to replace watch with embed/ in your code

Answer (score 0):

You can have your video start playing automatically when a user visits that page by adding a simple parameter to your YouTube URL

```
<iframe width="420" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k?autoplay=1">
</iframe>
```

Comment: What if I want to run this URL in the same iframe code `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XGSy3_Czz8k`